# Use Mysql column in subquery of subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

Reports

```
id     consultants
1      1,2,3,4
```

Users

```
id    name
1     John
2     Tom
```

When I try to run this query I get an error:    "Unknown column 'reports.consultants' in 'where clause'"

```
SELECT reports.id, 
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR ", ") from (SELECT name from users where users.id in (reports.consultants)) a) as consultant
FROM reports
```

I've thought of using a separate ReportConsultants table but I thought storing the consultants in the reports table may make the query more efficient and wondering if there is a way to do this. Using this kind of structure is also much simpler in the code.

Comment: See normalisation. Or don't bother with an RDBMS

Comment: First of all this is very bad design.

Comment: @Strawberry how do you recommend to design?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai how do you recommend to design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, the syntax needs to be slightly different

```
SELECT reports.id,
  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR ", ") from users where FIND_IN_SET(users.id, reports.consultants)) as consultant
FROM reports
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix your data structure!  You should not be storing lists of ids in a string.  Here are some reasons:

- Numbers should be stored as numbers, not strings.
- Ids should have declared foreign key constraints.
- SQL's strength is not string functions.

The right way to represent the data is with a junction table,

```
create table ReportConsultants (
    ReportConsultantId int auto_increment primary key,
    ReportId int,
    ConsultantId,
    constraint fk_reportconsults_report foreign key (reportid) references reports(reportid),
    constraint fk_reportconsults_consultant foreign key (consultantid) references consultants(consultantid)
);
```

Comment: The first column is (probably) redundant, but if an autoincrementing id is used, then it must be defined as (a component of) a PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely a way to go. I thought my way might make the query faster. Is there a way to get the subquery to use the field?

Comment: @ykay Amend your question accordingly.

Comment: @ykay Obviously, I mean once you've fixed your broken structure.

Comment: @ykay . . . Ask another question, once you have fixed the data structure.  Don't make significant revisions to a question after it has answers.